# Publish Axon Events onto a Kafka Topic

Tags: axon

I want to publish an event through one of my aggregate event handlers to the axon Kafka topic as I am using kafka as my event bus. What is the correct way to do that? Should I directly push the message to the topic or can I use `AggregateLifecycle#apply(event)` in this case?
I have multiple events getting published from my aggregate, through one of the event handlers I want to publish another event. I am using axon 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to start using the [Kafka Extension](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka) Axon provides. The shared repository contains all the necessary code to create a publishing end and a consuming end of Axon Event from and to a Kafka topic. For configuration convenience, there is a Spring Boot Starter present in that project too

Added, the repository has a (Kotlin) sample project showing how to configure it, which you can find [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka/tree/master/kafka-axon-example). Lastly, for a full description of how to set everything up, I strongly recommend to give Axon's Reference Guide a read, especially the Kafka page [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/kafka).

I'd like to recommend you thought that this extension is perfectly suited to communicate between Axon and non-Axon applications, making Kafka a form of "Enterprise Service Bus". Using it as *the* `EventBus` replacement within Axon Framework is doable, but requires a bunch of fine tuning on you rend. It would be wiser to use [Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server) instead in those scenarios, or if you really must, share the data source containing your events directly between the applications.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for your reply, I am already using axon kafka extension , I just want to publish a generic event message from outside my aggregate and I think I can use EventGateway provided by axon framework for this, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Aaah gotcha. That bit wasn't clear to me from your original question. The Axon Kafka Extension does not differentiate between events published from an Aggregate or those which you'd publish directly on the `EventGateway` or `EventBus`. It'll just ingest the event and put it on the Kafka topic you've configured. No worries there!

Comment: Thanks @Steven for confirming